# proof concerning "Neighboring fractions"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Brushing up on my Algebra skills with the book "Algebra" by I.M. Gelfand and reached a problem I am unable to solve.

> Fractions $a/b$ and $c/d$ are called neighboring fractions if their difference $\frac{ad-bc}{bd}$ has numerator $\pm1$, that is, $ad-bc = \pm1$.
>
> Prove
>   (a) In this case neither fraction can be simplified (that is, neither has any common factors in numerator or denominator).

What is a correct answer to this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is your question exactly? Also, please type out the problem rather than linking to a picture.

Comment: Hello. Hopefully you are able to see the image I linked. The problem is contained within.

Comment: Yes, I can see the image; please type it out. But what is your question?

Comment: Ok. I am asking for the solution to the problem - a proof

Comment: Thanks for writing it out; I've edited it to typeset the math. Have a look at the edits: in general, you can enclose a statement in dollar signs to typeset it (e.g. `$x+y$` to give $x+y$).

Comment: You beat me to it! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Assume one can be simplified, so for example $a=pk,b=qk$ with $k \gt 1$.  Plug that in and conclude you cannot have $ad-bc=\pm 1$

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Ross Millikan. This is a proof by contrapostive as I understand it. Is the following correct?

> Assume $a = pk$ and $ b = qk$  with $k > 1$. Then,
>
> $$
> {a\over b} - {c\over d} = {pk\over qk} - {c\over d} = {{dpk - qkc} \over qkd} = {k({dp-cq}) \over bd}  
> $$
>   ${k({dp-cq})} \ne \pm1$
>   Q.E.D.

Comment: This is effectively correct, but it would be good to justify the last line.